# Is there a way to have a conditional statement for comparing of tables using MySQL only?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, composer-php

I am having a dilemma from comparing my tables.

My problem is, I want to get each sum, which depends on the pricing. Here is the table.

Main table

```
    main_id   main_price   main_date_created
      25           8.5         2019-08-16
      26           11.5        2019-08-01
```

Total table

```
id    main_id    total_price   date_generated
1         25                10         2019-08-16     
2         25                10         2019-08-17
3         25                10         2019-08-18
4         25                10         2019-08-19
5         25                10         2019-08-20
6         25                10         2019-08-21
7         26                20         2019-08-01
8         26                 5         2019-08-02
9         26                 5         2019-08-03
10        26                10         2019-08-04
```

Price History table

```
id  main_id   changed_main_price   price_date_changed
1      25             15                    2019-08-18
2      26             20                    2019-08-03
```

I don't know if there is a way to do this just by using MySQL, what I am trying to achieve is, the `Total table` will be sum by MONTH and YEAR and will be multiplied by their designated price that depends on the date whether if the price has changed or not . the SUM will from each month will be generated by multiplying with the `main price` in the `Main table` but if the price had changed from its original price which it is on the `Price history table`

The output should be like this if the conditional is possible:

```
id   main_id  total_price         price_generated (which is the prices) date
1     25      170 (10+10*8.5)        8.5              
2     25      610 (10+10+10+10*15)   15
3     26      287.5 (20+5*11.5)      11.5
4     26      300    (5+10*20)       20
```

Here is my existing query,

```
SELECT m.main_id
     , m.main_price
     , SUM(t.total_price) total_generated
     , t.date_generated
  FROM main m
 INNER JOIN total t
    ON m.main_id = t.main_id
 GROUP 
    BY MONTH(t.date_generated);
```

I know that my query is not enough, and I still don't know if my idea is really possible :(.

Comment: It's possible. The only real issue is that you do not have a date range for the pricing. That can be derived from your tables but will complicate the query quite a bit. Basically, you would join the pricing table to itself or to the history table, and get the max (based on date) that is less that the date of the sale. Then join that to your transaction table and group by the main-id, YEAR(Total_Date_Generated), MONTH(Total_Date_Generated), with a sum of the total_price.

Comment: A better solution would be to have another column for the start of the pricing range.

Comment: Hi @SloanThrasher what will be the look in case i added a new column with the price table?

Comment: i replicated  your table structure and the data.. it seems kinda bit off and scattered. I cant connect the result you try to achieve.

Comment: Hi @dodzb thanks for the effort! Really appreciate it. I edited the structure again. Sorry if the structure is a really scattered. Anyways what im trying to achieve based on my structure is to create a billing cycle. In the ’’’main’’’ table the main price column is the original price. So if you total the sum of the ‘’’Price’’’ table based on the main_id which is the foreign key . It will be multiplied with the Main_price. But my problem is when the price is changed thats why there is a Price history table. I want to get all of the sum based on the date in MAIN table and will compare it.

Answer (score 0):

I racked my brain. hahaha  Is this you're after?

```
SELECT pricelist.id, pricelist.price, SUM(t.total_price),  SUM(t.total_price) * pricelist.price,
year( pricelist.latestdate), month(pricelist.latestdate),
year( t.total_date_generated), month(t.total_date_generated)
from totaltable as t

LEFT JOIN (
            (
            select main_id as id, main_price  as price, main_date_created as latestdate
            from maintable
            )
            UNION ALL
            (
            select total_main_id, changed_main_price , price_date_changed
            from pricehistorytable
            )
       ) as pricelist on  pricelist.id = t.total_main_id
GROUP BY    pricelist.id ,  t.total_price, pricelist.price,
year( pricelist.latestdate), month(pricelist.latestdate),
year( t.total_date_generated), month(t.total_date_generated) ;
```

Comment: hello. I tried it and im still not getting the right result. I tried to tweaked it because i think its just on the GROUP BY that needs to be fixed. But i still cant show the right answer. If the price in the main table has a date of ‘’’2019-08-01-2019-08-10” it should sum it and multiply it to its original price. And if from 2019-08-06 the price change so there will be two rows. The first row is the sum and total and will be multiply to the maon table price from the ‘’’2019-08-01 - 2019-08-05. The second row is from 2019-08-06 - 2019-08-10 and the sum of total is will be times in histor